# Django foreignkey not set when using an object instance

Tags: python, django, database

I bumped into a strange bug this morning and if anyone could explain to me why this fails it would be great.

Let say I have two really simple models:

```
class MoMo(models.Model):
    pass


class Objo(models.Model):
    hef_k = models.ForeignKey(MoMo, null=True, blank=True)
```

When I try to create one of them then adding a foreignkey this way:

```
from foreing_save import models

obj = models.Objo()
obj.save()
obj.hef_k = models.MoMo()
obj.hef_k.save()
obj.save()
```

the obj.hef_k seams to exists:

```
obj.hef_k
Out[9]: <MoMo: MoMo object>
```

But as soon as I refresh from db or simply get it again it's gone:

```
obj.refresh_from_db()

In [12]: obj.hef_k

In [13]: 

obj = Objo.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)

obj.hef_k

in [14]:
```

Do I miss something ? It seams strange to me and any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need first create model MoMo because now its doesnt exist ind DB and  see nothing.

Comment: You saved the foreign hef_k object but not the obj itself so it doesnt keep the new modification, you need to add obj.save()

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save `obj` after you added the related object, you only saved `obj.hef_k`.

Since the foreign key is an actual field on `obj` you need to save that object to record the fact that you have associated it with the Momo object.

```
obj = models.Objo()
obj.hef_k = models.MoMo()
obj.hef_k.save()
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create your second object because it doesn't exist in your database(don't have PK which is required for create relationship). All what you need is create `obj2` before assign them to `obj.href_k`:

```
obj2 = models.MoMo()
obj2.save()

obj = models.Objo()
obj.save()
obj.hef_k = obj2
obj.hef_k.save()
```

Comment: Sure, your way of doing works. But what I want to understand is why models.fk = Obj() way don't

Comment: @boblefrag This is answer to your question. ForeginKey needs PK of object so u need create object in DB to get PK for this object. And your model object is empty it's don't have any PK because its returned when you save this in model.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the second object before you can reference it. As long as it is not saved it has no primary key. In general it is is a good idea to use `<Model>.objects.create()` to produce new objects. It will save the object automatically.:

```
from foreing_save import models

obj = models.Objo()
obj.save()
obj.hef_k = models.MoMo.objects.create()
obj.hef_k.save()
```